# Time changed when merging files

Tags: r, datetime, merge

I am merging two files based on date and time (datetime).  When the files merge - the time component of one of the files has changed ie 2023-01-30 17:28:55 becomes 2023-01-30 07:28:55.  Both files have same structure.  I assume it is something simple but I can't work it out.   Here is an example from each file.  Greatly appreciate someone's help/advice.

```
File chipRTmerge
              Datetime            RecTemp            IMChipTemp     IMChip_Date              IMChip_Time
1            2023-01-30 17:28:55      38.5       39.7       2023-01-30        17:28:55
2            2023-01-30 17:35:37      41.2       42.9       2023-01-30        17:35:37
3            2023-01-30 17:37:06      41.2       42.5       2023-01-30        17:37:06
4            2023-01-30 17:38:27      40.9       42.2       2023-01-30        17:38:27
5            2023-01-30 17:39:23      41.8       42.0       2023-01-30        17:39:23
6            2023-01-30 17:40:07      41.1       41.9       2023-01-30        17:40:07
7            2023-01-30 17:40:46      41.4       41.8       2023-01-30        17:40:46
8            2023-01-30 17:41:38      41.1       41.7       2023-01-30        17:41:38
9            2023-01-30 17:43:24      41.1       41.6       2023-01-30        17:43:24
10          2023-01-30 17:43:25      41.4       41.6       2023-01-30        17:43:25

> str(chipRTmerge)
'data.frame':     34 obs. of  5 variables:
$ datetime   : POSIXct, format: "2023-01-30 17:28:55" "2023-01-30 17:35:37" "2023-01-30 17:37:06" "2023-01-30 17:38:27" ...
$ RecTemp    : num  38.5 41.2 41.2 40.9 41.8 41.1 41.4 41.1 41.1 41.4 ...
$ IMChip_Temp: num  39.7 42.9 42.5 42.2 42 41.9 41.8 41.7 41.6 41.6 ...
$ IMChip_Date: POSIXct, format: "2023-01-30" "2023-01-30" "2023-01-30" "2023-01-30" ...
$ IMChip_Time: chr  "17:28:55" "17:35:37" "17:37:06" "17:38:27" ...

File CT_BallChase
              Datetime            CorTemp
149        2023-01-30 17:35:09      40.39    
150        2023-01-30 17:35:19      40.44
151        2023-01-30 17:35:29      40.51
152        2023-01-30 17:35:39      40.57
153        2023-01-30 17:35:49      40.63
154        2023-01-30 17:35:59      40.69
155        2023-01-30 17:36:09      40.74
156        2023-01-30 17:36:19      40.81
157        2023-01-30 17:36:29      40.86
158        2023-01-30 17:36:39      40.91
159        2023-01-30 17:36:49      40.95
160        2023-01-30 17:36:59      40.99
161        2023-01-30 17:37:09      41.04
162        2023-01-30 17:37:19      41.07
163        2023-01-30 17:37:29      41.10
164        2023-01-30 17:37:49      41.16
165        2023-01-30 17:37:59      41.19
166        2023-01-30 17:38:09      41.2

tibble [429 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
$ datetime: POSIXct[1:429], format: "2023-01-30 17:10:19" "2023-01-30 17:10:29" "2023-01-30 17:10:39" "2023-01-30 17:10:49" ...
$ CorTemp : num [1:429] 38.3 38.3 38.3 38.3 38.3 ...
```

My code to merge them:

```
mergefile_CTIMCHIPRT_BC <-  merge(CT_BallChase, chipRTmerge, by="datetime", all=T,)
```

output has times changed for one file only (chipRTmerge) so just merges that file's data above the other file rather than integrating the results:

```
              
datetime            CorTemp            RecTemp            IMChip_Temp
1            2023-01-30 07:28:55      NA         38.5       39.7
2            2023-01-30 07:35:37      NA         41.2       42.9
3            2023-01-30 07:37:06      NA         41.2       42.5
4            2023-01-30 07:38:27      NA         40.9       42.2
5            2023-01-30 07:39:23      NA         41.8       42.0
6            2023-01-30 07:40:07      NA         41.1       41.9
7            2023-01-30 07:40:46      NA         41.4       41.8
8            2023-01-30 07:41:38      NA         41.1       41.7
```

Desired output

```
             Datetime            CorTemp    RecTemp            IMChip_Temp
1   2023-01-30 17:35:09      40.39    NA    NA
2   2023-01-30 17:35:19      40.44  NA  NA
3   2023-01-30 17:35:29      40.51  NA  NA
4   2023-01-30 17:35:37      NA         41.2       42.9
5   2023-01-30 17:35:39      40.57  NA  NA
6   2023-01-30 17:35:49      40.63  NA  NA
7   2023-01-30 17:35:59      40.69  NA  NA
8   2023-01-30 17:36:09      40.74  NA  NA
9   2023-01-30 17:36:19      40.81  NA  NA
10  2023-01-30 17:36:29      40.86  NA  NA
11   2023-01-30 17:36:39      40.91 NA  NA
12  2023-01-30 17:36:49      40.95  NA  NA
13   2023-01-30 17:36:59      40.99 NA  NA
14  2023-01-30 17:37:06      NA         41.2       42.5
15  2023-01-30 17:37:09      41.04  NA  NA
16  2023-01-30 17:37:19      41.07  NA  NA
17  2023-01-30 17:37:29      41.10  NA  NA
18   2023-01-30 17:37:49      41.16 NA  NA
19  2023-01-30 17:37:59      41.19  NA  NA
20  2023-01-30 17:38:09      41.2   NA  NA
21  2023-01-30 17:38:27      NA         40.9       42.2
```

Comment: Could you give us a sample of your data? You can do something like `dput(head(chipRTmerge))` to give us the first 6 lines of your data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  Trick for someone just learning R  - once I ran that little bit of code to give the first 6 lines of each file (which I have added above for your interest) - I could see that one file had UTC as the timezone and the other had no timezone specified.  So I just made them both UTC and now my files merge as they should.  Thank you - tricks for new players!!!